# How to format int to a bitstring of length n using format function in Python

Tags: python, binary, data-conversion

I am trying to convert an `int` to a binary string of length `n` using `format` function. I know how to do it for a fixed value of `n`, say `n=3` and I want to convert integer `6` to a bitstring of length `n=3`, then I can do `format(6, '03b')`.

May I know how to do the same for any given `n`? Clearly I cannot do `format(6,'0nb')`. So I'm wondering how to solve this?

Comment: Reopened. @q2w3e4, could you explain where you are stuck? Assign to the variable `n` and plug that variable into the second argument to `format()`.

Comment: @BradSolomon I don't know how to pass variable `n` to the second argument of `format()`.

Comment: `format(6, f'0{n}b')`…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is maybe a little misspoint but it use exact number of bit that are necessary to represent value, not a fixed value like `format(x, f"{n}b")`. Where `x` is some number, and `n` is number of bits.

```
import math

n = 6 # your number
format(n, f'0{int(math.log2(n))}b')
```

Here `n` is the number like `x` before, and there is no `n`, because we dynamicaly calculate right number of bits to repr `n`

Comment: That seems a contorted way of doing `format(n, f"0{n.bit_length()}b")` and skip the `import`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a formatted string to dynamically insert the number `n` into the string:

```
n = 6
format(6, f'0{n}b')
```